# Custom serialization in typescript is not happening as expected (Arrays are getting converted to Objects with spread)

Tags: json, typescript, serialization

## 1. The Problem

I am doing custom serialization in TypeScript as shown in example below.

I am serializing all strings as custom types. With the following approach, all the strings are getting replaced fine, but those **that are in arrays are getting returned as objects**. The expectation is that arrays should stay as arrays in returned new object and it should work fine for the strings that exist in both objects and arrays.

As extra info, I am serializing a custom type other than strings in my project, this is an example of what I am trying to do.

Any inputs?

## 2. The Code

```
interface Test {
  a: number;
  b: Array<string>
}

interface Sample {
  x: number;
  y: string;
  z: Array<Test>;
}

let sample: Sample = {
  x: 1,
  y: 'hello',
  z: [{ a: 10, b: ['hello', 'hi'] }]
};

function isObject(obj: any): boolean {
  return obj !== null && typeof obj === 'object';
}

function isString(obj: any): boolean {
  return obj !== null && typeof obj === 'string';
}

console.log(`${JSON.stringify(sample)}`);

function customSerializeRecursive(obj: any): any {
  const customTypePlaceHolder = {};

  for (const entry of Object.entries(obj)) {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    if (isString(value)) {
      customTypePlaceHolder[key] = {
        _type: 'test',
        _value: value.toString()
      };

    } else if (isObject(value)) {
      customTypePlaceHolder[key] = customSerializeRecursive(value);

    }
  }

  const newObj = { ...obj, ...customTypePlaceHolder };

  if (Object.keys(customTypePlaceHolder).length === 0) {
    return obj;
  } else {
    return newObj;
  }
}

const newSample = customSerializeRecursive(sample);
console.log(`${JSON.stringify(newSample)}`);
```

## 3. The Output

```
{
    "x": 1,
    "y": "hello",
    "z": [{"a": 10, "b": ["hello", "hi"]}]
}

{
    "x": 1,
    "y": {"_type": "test", "_value": "hello"},
    "z":{"0": {"a": 10, "b": {"0": {"_type": "test", "_value": "hello"}, "1": {"_type": "test", "_value": "hi"}}}}
}
```

- The first `json` shows the passed in object.
- The second `json` shows the returned object: we can see `z` getting converted to an object.

**Expected Output**

```
{
    "x": 1,
    "y": "hello",
    "z": [{"a": 10, "b": ["hello", "hi"]}]
}

{
    "x": 1,
    "y": {"_type": "test", "_value": "hello"},
    "z": [{"a": 10, "b": [{"_type": "test", "_value": "hello"}, {"_type": "test", "_value": "hi"}]}]
}
```

Comment: I do not see where you use isArray

Comment: I thought of adding some functionality to differentiate between object and array, but not sure how. sorry about that, right now it is doing nothing

Comment: Take it out of the code in the post then, so it easier to read for those who want to help. Anything unnecessary will hurt your ability to get help.

Comment: sure, have taken it out. Thanks

Comment: the issue is that Object.entries(['a', 'b']) will return you [["0","a"],["1","b"]], that's why after your manipulations you get the object instead of an array

Comment: I thought it is due to taking customTypePlaceHolder as an object for everything (for arrays also). do you suggest any different approach?

Comment: Could you please describe the result object which you are trying to achieve, it would help me to understand better

Comment: Am I right that you are trying to replace all strings to a { _type: 'test',  _value: value }?
And everything else should be as is?

Comment: I just updated the description with 'Expected Output', In real life I am trying to serialize an custom type other than string. And while deserializing I would like to get the exact same object that I passed as an input to 'customSeralizeRecursive', I will add the customDeserializeRecursive as well if you like. I had that ready, but the serialize function is not working properly.

Comment: Yes, you are right, converting strings to { _type: 'test', _value: value } is working fine. You might have already noticed that. The issue is with property 'z' of 'Sample' got converted to an object, we wanted to be an array. Yes everything else should be as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct answer to your questing will be like this:

```
const sample: Record<string, any> = {
    x: 1,
    y: 'hello',
    z: [{ a: 10, b: ['hello', 'hi'] }]
};

function replacer(key, value) {
    if (['_type', '_value'].includes(key)) {
        return value;
    }

    if (typeof value === 'string') {
        return {
            _type: 'test',
            _value: value,
        };
    }

    return value;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(sample, replacer, 2));
```

which will give you the following result:

```
{
  "x": 1,
  "y": {
    "_type": "test",
    "_value": "hello"
  },
  "z": [
    {
      "a": 10,
      "b": [
        {
          "_type": "test",
          "_value": "hello"
        },
        {
          "_type": "test",
          "_value": "hi"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

> But my gut tells me that you are trying to invent the wheel, so I would recommend you to check out [class-transformer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-transformer) which will help you manipulate plain objects to class and back.

P.S. If you are using typescript try to not use `any`.

Comment: thanks @D.Dimitrioglo,It solved the problem. I will try to learn class-transofrmer. Thanks.